# javascript pass parameter values to same named outer scope variables

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var a,b,c;

function abc(a,b,c){
   console.log("a is"+ a + ", b is"+ b + ", c is"+ c);
}

a; // undefined
b; // undefined
c; // undefined
```

I will be passing through strings `a`,`b`,`c`, but would like to also be able to access them once they are passed through the function.

So if I call `abc("d","e","f")`, I'd like that function to run using those three strings, but afterwards, outside of its own scope, I'd also like to be able to use `a="d"`, `b="e"`, and `f="f"`.

Could someone explain how this is done? I think that even though they are declared outside of the function, the fact that it's the same name is throwing me off.

I remember something in PHP about adding `&` before the parameter...

Thanks!

Comment: You're right about the names being the same. The arguments variables `shadows` the outter scope ones.

Comment: Why would you want this behaviour? It gives your code a smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking here, but it works just out of the box like you want it.

Since ECMAscript has *function scope*, the variables `a`, `b` and `c` will get locally resolved within the function context of `abc()`. The *outer* declarations of those 
*variable names* (lets call them *free variables*), will never get accessed because the *lookup process* will find those names first within its **own* context, resolve them and stop there.

If you just want to set those *free variables* which are part of a *parent context*, you probably should rename your *formal parameters* for convenience and then pass over the values

```
function abc(some, other, name) {
    a = some;
    b = other;
    c = name;
}
```

Hopefully that *parent scope* where `a`, `b` and `c` are declared is not the *global scope*. That is very correctly still considered bad practice and karma, for a couple of reasons.

Comment: aha! ok, so if I understand what you're saying, I can instead just name the parameters differently and set the variable names to the parameters within the function?!

Comment: @iight: yes, that would be the most convenient way I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice would be to give the inner variables different names, e.g. by prefixing them with 'inner' or the initials of the function name. Not only can you then simply assign the values to the outer variables with a simple `a = innerA`, but it also makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the variables in the outer scope if they're masked by function parameters with the same name.

You could, if they were named *properties* of a variable that is in the outer scope.  In browsers, global variables are actually just properties of the `window` variable:

```
var myobj = {};

function abc(a, b, c) {
    myobj.a = a;
    myobj.b = b;
    myobj.c = c;
}

// you can now use those values
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you mean:

```
var a, b, c;

function abc(_a, _b, _c) {
    a = _a;
    b = _b;
    c = _c;
}

abc(1, 2, 3);
console.log("a is"+ a + ", b is"+ b + ", c is"+ c); // 1, 2, 3
```

Given that said, I think this approach is not a good practise. Please organise them within a closure or a namespace. For example, here is an acceptable design pattern :

```
(function(g) {

    var _SomeClass = function(a, b, c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    _SomeClass.prototype = {
        printValues: function() {
            console.log(this.a, this.b, this.c);
        },
        doSomething: function() {
            // do something here
        },
        _privateMethod: function() {
            // should not be called from outside the closure
        }
    }

    g.SomeClass = _SomeClass;

})(window);

var myClass = new SomeClass(1, 2, 3);
myClass.printValues();
```